# Get actual sql statement employed behind a Db.Query call

Tags: postgresql, go

So, is there any way to archieve something like the `Db.Translate` func in the below example?

```
func printStatement(values []int64) {
    actualQueryAsString := Db.Translate(`
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE values = ANY($1)`, pq.Array(values))
    fmt.Println("The statement that will be used is :", actualQueryAsString)
}
```

I tried to find how to do it but ran out of ideas... thanks in advance.

Comment: Since I don't know go I'll just place it here to maybe give you some hint. As a workaround you could enable statement logging on server side for postgresql and investigate what's being executed

Comment: hint accepted! thanks @KamilG.